# How to pass query params from api gateway to aws lambda function implemented in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created an function aws lambda and it runs perfectly fine .

but Now I am deploying it and accessing it using api gateway .

I have created API gateway too.

this is my function

```
    import { DynamoDBClient, ScanCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { unmarshall } from '@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb';

const dbclient = new DynamoDBClient({
    region: 'us-west-2', // Replace 'us-west-2' with your desired AWS region
});

export const handler = async (event) => {

const skuId = event.skuid || event['queryStringParameters']['skuid']; 
try {
    const scanParams = {
        TableName: 'products',
    };

    const scanResponse = await dbclient.send(new ScanCommand(scanParams));
    const items = scanResponse.Items || [];

    const foundItem = items.find(item => {
        // Check if 'variants' exists and contains an array 'L' with the desired 'skuId'
        return (
            item.variants &&
            item.variants.L &&
            item.variants.L.some(variant => variant.M.sku.S === skuId)
        );
    });

    if (!foundItem) {
        return {
            statusCode: 404,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Item not found' }),
        };
    }

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(unmarshall(foundItem)),
    };
} catch (err) {
    return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: err.message }),
    };
}
```

};

I am passing skuid through query params

> https://vgwrjg6hog.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/my-resource?skuid=sku2441

Response :
{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'skuid')","trace":["TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'skuid')","    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:10:64)","    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1173:29)"]}

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you're seeing with any of an HTTP, REST or even Function URL in front of the Lambda *unless* I don't pass the URL parameter. Have you tried to print out the event?  Your code looks correct but it's unclear why you can't find the parameter.

Comment: I deleted my api gateway and its resources , and created again than it works .